# Equality or inequality

Tags: inequality

Sorry to make this foolish query. Does the following inequality is necessary?  (it is correct to use less or equal to), then the expressions on the left and right are equal or unequal it is actually as is presented below:

$$\frac{1}{M^2}\sum_{k\leq M} \sigma_k^2 \leq \frac{1}{M^2} \sum_{k=1}^M \sigma_k^2 ,$$

where $k \geq 1$ and $M \geq 1$, Or actually you are written?

$$\frac{1}{M^2}\sum_{k\leq M} \sigma_k^2 = \frac{1}{M^2} \sum_{k=1}^M \sigma_k^2 .$$

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I think they are equal but its not a problem to write $1\le1$

Comment: Thank you for your comment @rackne, but for the left k = 2, then $\frac{1}{M^2}\sum_{2\leq M} \sigma_k^2 \leq \frac{1}{M^2} \sum_{k=1}^M \sigma_k^2$, so we would have that inequality is a general relationship. What do you think?

Comment: If k is not a variable then left handside would go to infinity

Comment: Here k is variable, because $ k \geq 1$ and $k \leq M$.